# failed to build a release apk ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

Currently working on ionic-angular project , I want to generate a signed apk for my application , when i tried to use `ionic cordova build` i get a debug apk but when i add `--prod` or/and `--release` flag the apk wont install .
Those are my ionic info

```
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.6.1
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.4.1
@ionic/cli-utils                : 1.7.0
ionic (Ionic CLI)               : 3.7.0
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.0.2
Node              : v8.2.1
OS                : Linux 4.10
npm               : 5.3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Ionic release signed apk:

1) Add android platform with the CLI:

```
$   ionic platform add android
```

2)Now navigate to platforms/android with the CLI:

```
    $   cd platforms/android
```

3) Generate a key.store file with the CLI and answer all the questions:

```
    $  keytool -genkey -v -keystore YourApp.keystore -alias YourApp -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

4) Create 'ant.properties' file within ..\platforms\android and add below config detail

```
    key.store=YourApp.keystore
    key.alias=YourApp
    key.store.password=pass_123
    key.alias.password=pass_123
```

5) Create release-signing.properties file within ..\platforms\android and add below config detail

```
    storeFile=YourApp.keystore
    keyAlias=YourApp
    storePassword=pass_123
    keyPassword=pass_123
```

6) Run cmd

```
    $ ionic cordova build android --release
```